# extract number between characters - grep

Tags: php, bash, sed, grep

I am using PHP and want to extract numbers between characters `'gi|HERE IS THE NUMBER|'` using grep and assign it to variable.

The file contains:

```
>gi|1786181|gb|AE000111|ECAE000111 Escherichia coli , thrL, thrA, thrB, thrC, yaaA, yaaJ, talB, mog, yaaH genes from bases 1 to 10596
>gi|1786192|gb|AE000112|ECAE000112 Escherichia coli , htgA, yaaI, dnaK, dnaJ, yi81_1, yi82_1
```

I want to extract the number here: `gi|1786181|` and `gi|1786192|` and put them in x and y variables.

So, the output will be: `x=1786181` , `y=1786192`

I try:

```
$x = shell_exec("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe --login -c \" grep -o 'gi\|[0-9]\|'  $file.txt >  $result.txt 2>&1\"");
```

It did not work.
Any help please?

Comment: Why do you want `grep`? Why not in php itself?

Comment: As @anubhava said, use php; see [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use `grep` through the shell? Use [preg_match()](http://php.net/preg_match):

```
$input = file_get_contents('file.txt');
preg_match("/gi\|([0-9]+)\|/", $input, $matches);
```

`$matches` would return something like the following, the first item in the array contains the full match, the second just the values that you're after:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        "gi|1786181|",
        "gi|1786192|"
    ),
    1 => array(
        "1786181",
        "1786192"
    )
)
```

In either case, you'll need to specify that you require one or more integers:

```
gi\|([0-9]+)\|
```

Comment: @Alaa Read the documentation and find out!

Comment: @Egg Is it right to write:preg_match("/\|([0-9]+)\|/", $buffer, $matches);
$s = $matches[1]; echo $s; ?

Comment: @Egg Exactly what I want. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'gi|1786181|gb|AE000111|ECAE000111 Escherichia coli , thrL, thrA, thrB, thrC, yaaA, yaaJ, talB, mog, yaaH genes from bases 1 to 10596';
preg_match("/\|([0-9]+)\|/", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```